# Alt header logo and link for specific pages

Tags: theme-development, filters, logo

Building a WP site where two parent categories are styled to look like two distinct sections/sites.

I'm using the custom logo (set in Appearance/Customise) and using the function below I can successfully replace this with a custom logo on specific pages and categories. How can I also include a custom link rather than site home?

```
function change_logo_on_category($html) {

  if (is_page($page = '136'))

    $html = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)\/>/', '<img src="http://customlogo.png" class="custom-logo" alt="" itemprop="logo" />', $html);

  elseif ( in_category( 29 ) || post_is_in_descendant_category( 29 ))

    $html = preg_replace('/<img(.*?)\/>/', '<img src="http://customlogo.png" class="custom-logo" alt="" itemprop="logo" />', $html);

  return $html;   
}
add_filter('get_custom_logo','change_logo_on_category');
```

Comment: maybe you should think about a solution via css, each page have a single css class from the ID of the page and you can add the image via this selector.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using all possibilities of the [`get_custom_logo`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_custom_logo/) filter. As you can see from the source not only the `$html` is passed to it, but also the `$blog_id`. You can use the latter to do a `preg_replace` on the link like this:

```
add_filter ('get_custom_logo','wpse305624_change_logo_link',10,2);
function wpse305624_change_logo_link ($html,$blog_id) {
  $homelink = get_home_url ();
  $bloglink = get_permalink ($blog_id); // or anything else, for instance the blogs's parent
  $html = preg_replace ($homelink,$bloglink,$html);
  return $html;
  }
```

By the way, you could also use the filter on [`get_theme_mod`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_theme_mod/) (called at the beginning of `get_custom_logo`) to modify the returned image id in the first place, so you don't have to do a `preg_replace` afterwards. Unfortunately I don't see a similarly elegant way to manipulate the url.